# I have two buttons, how can I change one of the button's image if the other button is tapped? - Swift

Tags: swift, button, uiimage, selected

So I am making an app where the user will have to categorize their post between two options - "Lost" & "Found". Each button has the option to be clicked, but when I did the Testflight I got the comment that when they clicked the other button because they made a mistake, that the image stayed activated.

Is there a way to change the image of the other button back to the normal deselected image if the other button is clicked?

Here's my code:

```
 var lost = Bool()

@IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var breed: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var imagePosted: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var changeImageLostButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var changeImageFoundButton: UIButton!


//BUTTONS PRESSED - LOST & FOUND

@IBAction func lostPressedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    changeImageLostButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"LostButton-active.png"), for: .normal)
    lost = true
}



@IBAction func foundPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {

    changeImageFoundButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"FoundButton-active.png"), for: .normal)
    lost = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that while you set the image on each button when it is pressed, you don’t remove the image from the other one. All you need to do is remove the image from the appropriate button in the `lostPressedButton` and `foundPressedButton` methods:

```
@IBAction func lostPressedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  changeImageLostButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"LostButton-active.png"), for: .normal)

  // Remove the image on the found button.
  changeImageFoundButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)

  lost = true
}

@IBAction func foundPressedButton(_ sender: Any) {
  changeImageFoundButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"FoundButton-active.png"), for: .normal)

  // Remove the image on the lost button.
  changeImageLostButton.setImage(nil, for: .normal)

  lost = false
}
```